# Wordpress php href syntax error

Tags: php, wordpress, href

```
<?
<a href="https://www.example.com">php wp_title('|', true, 'right');</a>
?>
```

but syntax error :/,

Comment: if that's your exact code, then it's wrong. Plus, making sure short tags are enabled.

Comment: short tags enabled but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the coding exactly should do, given that it should be PHP, I would have expected that it should read

```
<a href="https://www.example.com"><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right');?></a>
```

At least, this would be valid PHP code...